# Using Fluent NHibernate with a Data Access Layer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, design-patterns, fluent-nhibernate

First a little background: I have a solution with the following 3 projects in it:

- MVC Project (User facing website)
- API Project (business logic project)
- Data Access Project (project where NHibernate lives)

I have the Fluent mappings in the DA layer, and (for now) I build the Hibernate `SessionFactory` in the GLobal.asax of the MVC site. This is not ideal as I want to have NHibernate completely contained in the DA layer and have the MVC app only communicate with the API layer. Also, I want to build the `SessionFactory` only once as it is an expensive operation.

To make things more complicated I have an inheritance structure like so:

- `User object` in API layer inherits from
- `User data object` in DA layer inherits from
- `Data object` in DA layer.

`Data object` is responsible for saving the object to the database as the saving function is the same across all objects and I do not want to repeat code. The problem I am having is how do I save the `User object` to the database from inside the `Data object` class while using a `SessionFactory` that I instantiated when the user logged into the website and can persist through out their session.

If anything is not explained clearly please let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do that would be using the [DI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection), with e.g. Unity.

Implement your `data object` having a constructor which takes for example an IRepository interface. The implementation of this interface handles the nHibernate session factory...

Your `data object` could also be generic where `T` is one for example `User data object`. Then you implement a methods in `data object` to e.g. save, update, delete `T` with the injected `IRepository`

pseudo code for a `data object`

```
public interface IEntity
{
}

public interface IRepository
{
    ISession Session { get; }
}

public class DataObjectBase<T> where T : IEntity
{
    private IRepository Repository { get; set; }

    public DataObjectBase(IRepository repository)
    {
        this.Repository = repository;
    }

    public T Get(int id)
    {
        return Repository.Session.Get<T>(id);
    }

    public void Save(T value)
    {
        Repository.Session.Save(value);
    }

    public void Update(T value)
    {
        Repository.Session.Update(value);
    }

    public void Delete(T value)
    {
        Repository.Session.Delete(value);
    }

    public IQueryable<T> Query()
    {
        return Repository.Session.Query<T>();
    }
}
```

Implementation of your specific data object

```
public class ADataObject : IEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // [...]
}
```

Implementation of your data context for the data object

```
public class ADataObjectContext : DataObjectBase<ADataObject>
{
    public ADataObjectContext(IRepository repository)
        : base(repository)
    {
    }
}
```

A simple example test using Unity

```
public class Test
{
    public void Run()
    {
        IUnityContainer myContainer = new UnityContainer();
        myContainer.RegisterType<IRepository, NHibernateRepository>();

        var ctx = myContainer.Resolve<ADataObjectContext>();

        var obj = ctx.Query().Where(p => p.Id == 2);
    }
}
```

Of cause you would have to implement the `NHibernateRespository` to do whatever you want it to.

The `UnityContainer` initialization should be done within your `global.asax` within the MVC project. You can also configure Unity via web.config.

The `NHibernateRespository` should actually be a singleton. This can either be implemented by you, or you simply use the Unity functionality to instantiate your type as singleton. The `new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager()` does exactly that.

Instead of exposing the session as a property you can of cause expose a method which opens a new session. Or you implement a Begin and End unit of work, which is common practice in web environments...

Other links for a normal repository pattern, and unit of work, unity... or simply search on Google for nhibernate repository pattern

http://slynetblog.blogspot.de/2011/11/in-spite-of-common-now-approach-of.html

http://blog.bobcravens.com/2010/07/using-nhibernate-in-asp-net-mvc/

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203101.aspx

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I am unfamiliar with DI implementation so I was hoping I could do this without DI, but I guess this gives me an excuse to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this options:

- Using AOP: when a function is called in API layer, AOP creates a session and passes the value parameters in methods or constructors to DA layer.
- From MVC project to DA layer, it passes a session to DA layer with parameters in method o constructors, through all the layers.

Thinks the session is always associated with the interface layer.